# Node.js Getting Module Name from instance

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my Node.js app, after I require all my modules into my server.js, then I am passing their instances into my function. My function needs to figure out which module is passed and it will call corresponding file.

I tried to get module name by following way but I could not get it done.

Is there any way to extract module name? It can be object name as well.

this is my server js file

```
var less = require("less");
var express = require("express");
var path = require('path');
var MyApp = require("./LocalModules/MyApp.js");
MyApp.InitializeAll([less, express]);
```

And this is where I need to resolve module name.

```
exports.InitializeAll = function (modules) {
    for (var i = 0; i < modules.length; i++) {
        var currentModule = modules[i];
        var localModuleName = "MyApp_" + currentModule.constructor.name + ".js";
        var appModule = require(localModuleName);
        appModule.Initialize(currentModule);
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass the modules as an object, that way you can just get the keys

```
MyApp.InitializeAll({less : less, express : express});
```

and then do

```
exports.InitializeAll = function (modules) {

    for (var module in modules) {

        var currentModule   = modules[module];
        var localModuleName = "MyApp_" + module + ".js";
        var appModule       = require(localModuleName);

        appModule.Initialize(currentModule);
    };

}
```

Comment: This is correct, thanks for pointing this out, already works :)